# How to validate string fields using constant values from object?

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I want to take this code and enhance it to have the String values saved as constants

```
const toValidate = Joi.object({
    emailTiming: Joi.string().valid('DAILY','WEEKLY','MONTHLY','QUARTERLY','MEDIAN','YEARLY').required()
});
```

So I created this object:

```
  EMAIL_DISPATCH_TIMING: {
    DAILY: 'DAILY', 
    WEEKLY: 'WEEKLY', 
    MONTHLY: 'MONTHLY', 
    QUARTERLY: 'QUARTERLY', 
    MEDIAN: 'MEDIAN', 
    YEARLY: 'YEARLY'
  }
```

I wanted to know how can I get the values from this object and set them as valid values to my field.

Currently I tried this, and it didn't work -

```
emailTiming: Joi.string().valid(Object.values(EMAIL_DISPATCH_TIMING)).required(),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`valid`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.8.3#anyvalidvalues---aliases-equal) accepts a rest parameter, therefore you need to use the spread operator:

```
const items = {
  DAILY: 'DAILY',
  WEEKLY: 'WEEKLY',
  MONTHLY: 'MONTHLY',
  QUARTERLY: 'QUARTERLY',
  MEDIAN: 'MEDIAN',
  YEARLY: 'YEARLY'
};

const toValidate = Joi.object({
  emailTiming: Joi.string().valid(...Object.values(items)).required()
});
```